# jquery sortable adding element

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable, drag

I am using jquery sortable to drag and drop elements from one list to another. But this will move elements from one list to another. 
I am looking for a functionality where it adds element into second list when i drag it from first list. so after dragging the element should be in both the list.
any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: i am doing exactly the same as the example in this list. here i need dragged elements to be added instead of being moved. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Answer (score 0):

Like in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/1xnmtyqs/), set your helper to 'clone'.

JS

```
$('.dragme div').draggable({
                            axis: 'y',
                            helper: 'clone',
                            opacity: '0.5'
});
$('.dropme').droppable({
    accept: '.dragme div',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
    }

});
```